# Which database schema should i use?

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, database-design, devops

I am building a Rest Api using node, MySQL and MongoDB, but i am confused with the database schema to go for as the business case is B2B and for each business(customer) there is like 10 tables for general ledger, products, transactions, clients, sales, purchase and many like these. and for accommodating 1 to N relationship in sales and purchase record i will use MongoDB to avoid making default MAX number of columns for products in the purchase/sale orders in SQL.
Considering my customers need a separate data backup option for their data and in near future i am also planning to integrate the relationships between the application customers.

So, which is the best option to go for. I have read this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260798/500-databases-or-1-database-with-500-tables-or-just-1-table-with-all-the-records) and answers quite carefully, and would like to ask whether should I go for option number 2 ?

Also, I would like to ask whether I should separate my entire backend (DB +Server) for specific `BUSINESS TYPES` using hostname mapping to business specific azure WebApp ?

Comment: You'll need to design your solution more before you work out the schema. First work out the problem your product is solving, then determine the right way to solve it. Coming out of that will be the first hints of your architecture. You seem to be jumping to the implementation of the solution before you have a solid design. The option you pick in that question will be clear when you have a more solid solution. Think about security issues, the lifecycle of data, privacy issues, hosting issues, customer requirements and too much more to mention. Just start small and local, see how it works out.

Comment: Hey @DavidThomas, I am already up and running for single business case and now heading to restructure for accommodating multi tenancy, So just wanted to make sure of the base of the application to be robust and appropriate one. Can you help with your thoughts over scaling for multi tenancy ? I don't think trying every possible architecture is a good option..